# Get Values out of Complex Perl Hash Structures

Tags: perl, hash, reference, hashmap, dereference

With the following Code I can fetch Data stored in a Hash from a Database and print it out:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $fdx = $s->field();   # get Hashreference from Database
print Dumper($fdx);      # print out Hash
```

The (important part of the) Output looks like this:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
     'selectable' => 'true',
     '_PARENT_OBJECT' => bless( {
           'dirtyFlag' => 1,
           'path' => undef,
           'testItems' => [],
           'data' => {
                'TEST_10' => {
                     'atm_rundatahistory' => {
                           '1523964918' => {
                                'atm_prid' => {
                                      'content' => '',
                                      'label' => 'Problem Report IDs',
                                      'raw' => ''
                                 }, ...
                            '1523964410' => {
                                 'atm_prid' => {
                                       'label' => 'Problem Report IDs',
                                       'raw' => '23361234',
                                       'content' => '23361234'
                                  }, ...
```

**'Test_10'** is one of hundreds of Tests, **'1523964918'** is one of many unix timestamps, so basically its a 32 Bit Integer, but I dont know which numbers the timestamps contain.

**How do I print out / access the values for *'content'* (in this case '23361234') of the most inner Hashes, for all Tests and unix timestamps, if they exist?**

---

*from here on I will describe my thoughts and what I have tried, its not necessary to read any further for this question.*

I think the code I am looking for is something like:

```
foreach my $val($fdx{_PARENT_OBJECT}{data}{"TEST_*"}{atm_rundatahistory}{"********"}{atm_prid}{content}) 
    print("\n$val");
```

However I don't know the exact Syntax, and neither do I know which placeholders to set for `"Test_10"`, since there are many tests numbers, e.g. `"...Test_132...Test_134"` and the Unix timestamps can be any 32 Bit Integer, so I guess I can use start as a placeholder? e.g. `"********"`.

After some hours of searching on the web, I haven't found a understandable tutorial on how to access values from complex Perl hash structures, I guess there are some simple syntax-rules to know and you can get any value of even very complex data structures without to much effort.

I've already read [perldoc_perlreftut](https://perldoc.pl/perlreftut#Using-References). If there is any other easy to understandable tutorial for these kind of problems, please recommend them to me. I don't really know how I can learn to handle such complex data structures in Perl myself.

Comment: Your `$fdx` contains an object, which in turn contains other objects, but you cut off the class names. It looks like you are using proprietary code to get the data from your database, so we can't tell you how to do this using your code's built-in mechanics. You should not, however, poke around in the object internals, as Perl's way of implementing objects allows those to change and there is no guarantee that your code won't suddenly break if you mess with internals. Instead, install Data::Printer and use it to inspect the object. `use Data::Printer class => { expand => 'all' }; p $fdx`...

Comment: ... you can then check what kind of methods are available, whether there is a way to iterate or search the data, and so on. If this is code proprietary to your organisation, you should read the actual classes' code and hopefully it will contain documentation. If it is indeed open source, you should do the same.

Comment: hey, thank you very much for your answer, i will try this now. So whenever there is a bless on a hash it is some sort of class and has eventually own methods ? also i only want to read out data, not change anything

Comment: Yes. `bless` is the keyword that combines a data structure with a package, turning it into an _object_. We use the word _class_ loosely in Perl for packages that have an object-oriented interface. You can spot _methods_ (which are just subs) by their first argument being `$self`, which is the naming convention for the object itself. Calling `$foo->frobnicate($bar)` will look like `package Foo; sub frobnicate { my ( $self, $bar ) = @_; ... } 1;`. The arrow operator `->` takes the package the thing on the left is blessed into to find the method on the right and passes the thing on the left to it

Comment: Please note that you could indeed just reach into the data structure. There is no such thing as a _placeholder_ for a key. You need to _iterate_ over all keys using a loop. This is fairly simple. You will need to use the `keys` keyword, and at least one `foreach` loop. But doing this with objects is **really bad practice**, as it could break any time, and it will be very hard to maintain as you create coupling where there shouldn't be any. I can't tell you how to do this properly as I don't know your system, but I can tell you what kind of thing you need to do.

Comment: currently installing Data::Printer, so basically that would be like 6 or 7 nested foreach loops, each going one step 'deeper' into the hash structure? thanks for you help, sadly i dont have the reputation yet to upvote :/

Comment: after installing Data::Printer `use Data::Printer class => { expand => 'all' }; p $fdx;` doesnt give any output. seems to work though, there are no errors.

Comment: I've not actually answered, this is just comments. Voting on them has no effect but to filter for later viewers. Your `p` output goes to `STDERR`. If this is in a web application, it'll be in your server log. Use `print np $foo` instead to write to `STDOUT`.

Comment: You don't need 6 or 7 loops if the other keys are fixed. You only need them for dynamic keys. From your description, it looks like `_PARENT_OBJECT`, `data` and `atm_rundatahistory` are fixed, and so are the values inside each timestamp.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182431/discussion-between-simbabque-and-captaincovfefe).